# Download a file using curl from a php server

Tags: curl

I'm trying to write a script that will download all the source material from the tutorials at lazyfoo.net. An example download link for the file is

http://lazyfoo.net/downloads/index.php?file=SDLTut_lesson16

I use this command:

`curl http://lazyfoo.net/downloads/index.php?file=SDLTut_lesson13 --O lesson13.zip`

This gets me this response and no file:

```
 % Total    % Received % Xferd  Average Speed   Time    Time     Time  Current
                                Dload  Upload   Total   Spent    Left  Speed
 0     0    0     0    0     0      0      0 --:--:-- --:--:-- --:--:--     0
```

Am I missing something obvious?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You are getting a 302 redirect. Use the `-L` option

```
curl http://lazyfoo.net/downloads/index.php?file=SDLTut_lesson13 -L --O lesson13.zip
```

Also in future `-v` (stands for verbose) is useful for debugging.