# Download a file through a server script via curl

Tags: http, curl, escaping

So I'm trying to download a file that works fine in the browser, but will simply not work using curl:

> $ curl http://www.partner.viator.com/partner/admin/tools/links_feeds/downloadFeed.jspa?feed=Products&PUID=10869 -L --O full_viator_product_list.zip

I get:

```
[1] 10097
-L: command not found
```

What am I doing wrong?

*(Just to prove I've done some homework, the issue [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9122914/download-a-file-using-curl-from-a-php-server) did not help.)*

Comment: The solution to this problem was to wrap the URL in quotes.

Answer (score 0):

See the `&` in the url? that's where it goes wrong. On the Linux command line, this basically means 'run the command in the background, and continue to the next command, if any'. 
If you put the entire url in quotes, it will work:

```
curl 'http://www.partner.viator.com/partner/admin/tools/links_feeds/downloadFeed.jspa?feed=Products&PUID=10869' -L --O full_viator_product_list.zip
```

When using commands like this, make sure you always either quote or escape them. If you don't do this, nastier things than this problem can happen.